# Can you factor equations which has $e^{-x}$ and $x$ together?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am working on a math investigation, and I got a function: $y = 5x - 2e^{-4x} + 2$. The problem is, I want to change this equation such that $x$ is in terms of $y$.

Is there a way so? Or is it impossible since there's both $x$ and $e^x$?

Answer (score 1):

In, (what I guess is) your context, the answer is "it's impossible."  You won't find an algebraic expression of $x$ in terms of $y$ using the most common functions.

However, by introducing new functions, such as the Lambert Omega function:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

we can get solutions to such equations.  Such solutions are unsatisfying for most people, because all we've done is essentially define the answer.

Comment: The last sentence is interesting because to some extent, you could say the same for many (inverse) functions, e.g. $x^3 = y \implies x = \color{blue}{\sqrt[3]{y}}$ or $\sin x = y \implies x = \color{blue}{\arcsin y}$ (I'm omitting some restrictions here). I agree with your answer but I think the (level of) _unsatisfied feeling_ has more to do with how _common / widely used_ these functions are and not so much with the fact they're definitions and simply 'hide' the problem in some sense.

Comment: @StackTD  I agree.  I've asserted to some of my students that "three" is a very abstract concept and the only reason they're comfortable with it is that they've been using the concept since age three.